# Appending writes to hdf5 file in fortran

Tags: fortran, hdf5

I would like to write data into hdf5 file in fortran in an appended way, but I can't hold the data in a large memory array.

when writing using ascii I can do something like:

```
program example1
implicit none
integer :: nu, i
open(filename="someFile.txt", newunit=nu)
do i = 1, 10
   write(nu, *) i
end do
close(nu)
end program example1
```

and what I would get is a file holding all of the integer numbers from 1 to 10 but without declaring a size 10 one dimensional array.

How can I write a hdf5 file in fortran that does exactly that, i.e holding the numbers in the same file under the same dataset name but without holding an array that holds these numbers?

Comment: You want to use an Extendible Dataset. This is well documetned in THE HDF Group documentation. Start here: [Extendible Datasets](https://portal.hdfgroup.org/display/HDF5/Extendible+Datasets)  There are code examples here: [HDF5 Examples from Learning The Basics](https://portal.hdfgroup.org/display/HDF5/Examples+from+Learning+the+Basics)

Comment: These links were helpful - though not straightforward. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You need to create an extendible dataset and then populate it with the help of an hyperslab or point selection (otherwise, previously written data will be overwritten). Using [HDFql](https://www.hdfql.com), your use-case can be solved as follows in Fortran:

```fortran
PROGRAM Example

      USE HDFql

      CHARACTER :: variable_number
      INTEGER :: state
      INTEGER :: i

      state = hdfql_execute("CREATE AND USE FILE test.h5")
      state = hdfql_execute("CREATE DATASET dset AS INT(0 TO UNLIMITED)")

      WRITE(variable_number, "(I0)") hdfql_variable_register(i)

      DO i = 1, 10
            state = hdfql_execute("ALTER DIMENSION dset TO +1")
            state = hdfql_execute("INSERT INTO dset[-1] VALUES FROM MEMORY " // variable_number)
      END DO

      state = hdfql_variable_unregister(i)
      state = hdfql_execute("CLOSE FILE")

END PROGRAM
```